# Web speech API security

Tags: javascript

Does the web speech API send the audio to a third-party web service in order to do the speech-to-text conversion, or is everything built into the browser?

I'm trying to work out how secure this API is, for example as implemented in Chrome 25.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The speech input API specification doesn't mention how it should be implemented. But in the requirements section there is a bullet point about encrypting communications with remote speech servers[1], it's a not a requirement for now.
As for Chrome, it seems to be using a remote speech to text server using a POST over https according to this article[2], note this it's about Chrome 11 and it might have changed in the recent release.

1. http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-xg-htmlspeech/2011Feb/att-0020/api-draft.html#requirements_section
2. http://mikepultz.com/2011/03/accessing-google-speech-api-chrome-11/